# Prevent regex group from including previous character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to get any words starting with @, such as in "@word", but only get the "word" value.

My sample text is:

```
@bob asodija qwwiq qwe @john @cat asdasd@qeqwe
```

My current regex is:

```
/\B@(\w+)/gi
```

This works perfectly, except that "@" is still being captured. The output of this match is:

```
"@bob"
"@john"
"@cat"
```

I've tried setting the @ in a back reference, but its still including the @ in the results.

```
/\B(?:@)(\w+)/gi
```

Comment: FYI, It isn't *capturing* the `@`, it's *consuming* it.  A non-capturing group merely allows you to group things without also assigning a separate "handle" to that portion of the match.  It's still part of the overall match, which is what you're seeing.  The only kind of group that *doesn't* consume what it matches (in JavaScript, at least) is a lookahead--e.g. `(?=...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat trick using the [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, which can take a function as the replacement.

```
var matches = [];
var str = "@bob asodija qwwiq qwe @john @cat asdasd@qeqwe";

str.replace( /\B@(\w+)/g, function( all, firstCaptureGroup ) {
    matches.push( firstCaptureGroup );
});
console.log( matches ); //["bob", "john", "cat"]
```

Comment: I can't decide whether to be tickled or appalled.  +1 anyway; it's a *fun* kind of appalling. :D

Comment: @AlanMoore - In my defence: This trick is not beneath John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the match array returned from [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```
var teststr = '@bob asodija qwwiq qwe @john @cat asdasd@qeqwe';
var exp = /\B@(\w+)/gi;

var match = exp.exec(teststr);
while(match != null){
    alert(match[1]); // match 1 = 1st group captured
    match = exp.exec(teststr);
}
```

Comment: To clarify paul's answer, if you have capture groups in your regex, like parens, string.match or regex.exec will return an array, and the first result of that array is the FULL match. The next elements in the array are the capture groups.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a better solution without additional calculations except of regular expression:

```
(?<=\B@)(\w+)
```

Comment: ...and if you use lookbehind, you don't need the capturing parentheses any more.

Comment: So if you have an array of found strings why can't you simply remove N first characters from each string, where N is a length of your "@" or another string?